# Issue in showing kanban image in odoo 11

Tags: odoo-10, odoo-11

When i add an image field in kanban view in odoo11 it has raised the error as "QWeb2 - template['kanban-box']: Runtime Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'raw_value' of undefined" ". And the same code worked for me in odoo 9. I'm struck in identifying the cause of the issue. Here's my code.

**Python Code**:

```
class Test(models.Model):
    _name = "test.test"
    image = fields.Binary(attachment=True)
```

**XML Code**:

```
<record id = "test_id" model = "ir.ui.view">
        <field name = "name">Test Image</field>
        <field name = "model">test.test</field>
        <field name = "arch" type = "xml">
            <kanban>
              <field name="image" />
               <templates>
                <t t-name="kanban-box">
                        <div class="oe_resource_vignette">                    
                            <div class="oe_resource_image">
                                    <img  t-att-src="kanban_image('test.test','image',record.id.raw_value)"  class="oe_resource_picture"/>

                         </div>
                 </templates>
            </kanban>
       </field>
  </record>
```

Thanks for your support and time.

Comment: Try to give string to your field and then execute code. Might work don't know exactly.

Comment: Thanks for your's reply i have tried as you said but it does't work it has raised the same error

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the `id` field to the kanban view (in any view) if you will be referencing it.  This applies up to Odoo 14 as well.

Added `<field name="id" attrs="{'invisible': True}"/>` to code below:

```
<record id = "test_id" model = "ir.ui.view">
        <field name = "name">Test Image</field>
        <field name = "model">test.test</field>
        <field name = "arch" type = "xml">
            <kanban>
              <field name="image" />
               <templates>
                <t t-name="kanban-box">
                        <div class="oe_resource_vignette">                    
                            <div class="oe_resource_image">
                                    <img  t-att-src="kanban_image('test.test','image',record.id.raw_value)"  class="oe_resource_picture"/>
                         </div>
                 </templates>
                 <field name="id" attrs="{'invisible': True}"/>
            </kanban>
       </field>
  </record>
```

Kanban Docs: https://www.odoo.com/documentation/11.0/howtos/backend.html#kanban

Answer (score 0):

you can try it by adding the "id"

```
<record id = "test_id" model = "ir.ui.view">
    <field name = "name">Test Image</field>
    <field name = "model">test.test</field>
    <field name = "arch" type = "xml">
        <kanban>
          <field name="id"/>
          <field name="image"/>
           <templates>
            <t t-name="kanban-box">
                    <div class="oe_resource_vignette">                    
                        <div class="oe_resource_image">
                                <img  t-att-src="kanban_image('test.test','image',record.id.raw_value)"  class="oe_resource_picture"/>

                     </div>
             </templates>
        </kanban>
   </field>
```